# Como preencher uma coluna de um dataframe pandas usando valores correspondentes de outra coluna em outro dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data.frame

Olá. Estou trabalhando em um projeto pessoal e preciso de uma ajuda. Tenho 2 dataframes:

```
solicitacoes = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,4,5],
                             'Equipe':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                             'Emissor_da_ordem':['Joao Pedro','Maria Teresa', 'Ricardo Duarte', 'Iago Matos', 'Tiago Nogueira'],
                             'Emissor_da_ordem_login':['AD_JP','CR_MT','AD_RD','0345','321'],
                             })

incidentes = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[7,8,9,10,11],
                           'Equipe':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                           'Emissor_da_ordem':'',
                           'Emissor_da_ordem_login':['AD_JP','CR_LD','AD_RD','0345','9999']
                           })
```

Eu gostaria de preencher cada linha da coluna incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem'] com o nome do seu emissor a partir do seu respectivo login (  incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem_login'] ). Ex.: Preencher a primeira linha da coluna incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem'] = 'Joao Pedro'.Para isso eu tenho o dataframe solicitacoes.

Como eu posso fazer isso com o pandas?

Obs.: As duas tabelas são geradas pelo mesmo sistema e um login corresponde a apenas uma pessoa. 
Obs2: Alguns valores em incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem_login'] podem não serem encontrados em solicitacoes['Emissor_da_ordem_login'].

Desde já, muito obrigado

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT, Leonardo! Sua pergunta esta faltando algumas informações para a total compreensão do problema. Por favor leia [como criar um exemplo minimo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Aproveite e adicione na pergunta como deve ser a saída da resposta correta.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi tão bem sua pergunta, mas acredito que você esteja procurando por isso:

```
emissores = []
for emissor_ordem, emissor_solic, emissor_inci in zip(solicitacoes['Emissor_da_ordem'], solicitacoes['Emissor_da_ordem_login'], incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem_login']):
    if  emissor_solic==emissor_inci:
        emissores.append(emissor_ordem)
    else:
        emissores.append('')
incidentes['Emissor_da_ordem_login'] = emissores
```

Onde os emissores não eram iguais, inseri uma string vazia.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas tente algo com o comando "merge" do pandas(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Talvez consiga com algo como:

```
novo_df = pd.merge(solicatoes, incidentes, on=['Emissor_da_ordem_login'])
```